# why does angularjs blank out the input field when ng-maxlength is exceeded on initialization?

Tags: angularjs, ng-maxlength

If I have an input text field whose value is exceeding the ng-maxlength upon form load (the input is still $pristine, not $dirty), the input field is misleadingly blank, while the ng-model still has data.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uUaC9tgHEozBkUReRXBk?p=preview

I want the input to present the same data as what the modal has, why is it showing me a blank?

Is this a bug?  Or intended behavior?

Comment: This seems to be the default behavior for angularjs, as ng-invalid tag is already emitted.

Comment: What if I want to show the existing value to the user so they can fix the length?

Comment: See this discussion https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1412

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because after exceeding the ng-maxlength criteria, angular js treats the input as undefined.
You can use html maxlength attribute with the ng-maxlength. Html maxlength will restrict the input value to that limit only and ng-model will store the input value for the limited length only. And you can use ng-maxlength for showing error upon exceeding the limit.

Comment: that works if you start with something short and try to exceed the max length.  However if your form is prepopulated with a string that already exceeds the max-length and you attempt to shorten the string, the model data will go blank until the validation passes.  I wonder if there is a way to prevent that undefined behavior and keep the value the same as the view value?

Comment: If the form starts with the populated string that already exceeds the max-length then you should try to do checking for max-length in the controller itself..

Answer (score 2):

adding `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"` to the html element fixed this for me.